# Different Highcharts in same component (Angular 5)

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am trying to display multiple highcharts in the same component using Angular 5. Data for both the highcharts will be different. As am new to angular could anyone give insight on how to proceed to add another Highchart here. The following is typescript and HTML file.
Thanks

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { chart } from 'highcharts';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Highcharts + Angular 5';

  @ViewChild('chartTarget') chartTarget: ElementRef;

  chart: Highcharts.ChartObject;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const options: Highcharts.Options = {
      chart: {
    type: 'column'
},
title: {
    text: 'Stacked column chart'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
},
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
        text: 'Bitbucket Consumption in TBs'
    },
    stackLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
        }
    }
},
legend: {
    align: 'right',
    x: -30,
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 25,
    floating: true,
    borderColor: '#CCC',
    borderWidth: 1,
    shadow: false
},
tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
},
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
        }
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'CTC',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
}, {
    name: 'ASW',
    data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
}, {
    name: 'MQS',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
}]
};


this.chart = chart(this.chartTarget.nativeElement, options);
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
</div>

<div>
  <button (click)="addSeries()">Add Series</button>
</div>
<div #chartTarget>
  chart target
</div>
```

How should I add another div here so that a different Highchart can be used here ?

**EDIT:**
Here I tried incorporating Andrew's suggestion but for some reason the view still doesnt has the other chart visible.
https://angular-5h9k9m.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add a new div, reference it, etc.

**app.component.html**

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
</div>

<div>
  <button (click)="addSeries()">Add Series</button>
</div>
<div #chartTarget>
  chart target
</div>
<div #chartTarget2>
  chart target
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { chart } from 'highcharts';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  title = 'Highcharts + Angular 5';

  @ViewChild('chartTarget') chartTarget: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('chartTarget2') chartTarget2: ElementRef;

  chart: Highcharts.ChartObject;
  chart2: Highcharts.ChartObject;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const options: Highcharts.Options = {
      chart: {
        type: 'column'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Stacked column chart'
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
      },
      yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
          text: 'Bitbucket Consumption in TBs'
        },
        stackLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
          }
        }
      },
      legend: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -30,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
        floating: true,
        borderColor: '#CCC',
        borderWidth: 1,
        shadow: false
      },
      tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        column: {
          stacking: 'normal',
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
          }
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'CTC',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
      }, {
        name: 'ASW',
        data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
      }, {
        name: 'MQS',
        data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
      }]
    };


    this.chart = chart(this.chartTarget.nativeElement, options);
    this.chart2 = chart(this.chartTarget2.nativeElement, options); // maybe use different options
  }
}
```

Comment: @Shaurya https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1pu3e3 You didn't copy the entire code...

Comment: Thanks... @Andrew